# What is the meaning of 晦 in the phrase 韬光养晦?

Tags: meaning, chengyu

I find the phrase 韬光养晦 in a context,and I look up it in the dictionary,it means hidden talents, do not make the leakage.But I still don't know the meaning of 晦.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

晦 means some place which is dark.

韬光养晦 means hide one's talent and keep a low profile

Comment: This should be the right answer. As Roti said, `晦 means some place which is dark`, 晦 is not suggest the weakness. 养晦 means being a solitary, hiding yourself from time. It's an old phase and having extension meaning already. ref. [zdic](http://www.zdic.net/c/b/37/85250.htm)

Answer (score 3):

晦's original meaning is dark moonless night, here it figuratively means the lack of accomplishment or culture. And other words' meanings are:

韬 : restrain, hide
光 : shine, ray of light, here it figuratively means talent
养 : cultivate, train

So 韬光养晦 means to hide talent and keep improving, to achieve balanced development.

Comment: 晦 is not `lack of accomplishment or culture` here, 養晦 came from 遵時養晦 from The Book of Songs (詩經) and said that the King Wu of Zhou(周武王) knew how to judge the situation, retreated and hided their trace. Here 晦 means some place (too dark) that cannot be seen.

Comment: Please refer to Roti's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The literal meaning of '晦' is the dark night, without the moonlight, as @songyuanyao said.
and in this idiom, '晦' means one's shortcoming, weakness, opposite to strong and advantage.

So you can comprehend this idiom in this way: In order to survive, one needs to hide his talent and pretend to be weak, so that he can get enough time to be strong and defeat his opponent.

Answer (score 0):

韬 is hide
光 is light or something shining here it means your brilliant ideas, 晦 is implicit   or something bad and weak
养 is improve or change
韬光养晦 means no showing your power, just improve yourself